# What is the time complexity of this function which calculates the size of an image on a contact sheet?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

So I recently started my studies on data structures and algorithms, specifically big O notation. I get the basics so far. As an exercise I wanted to determine the time complexity of an algorithm I wrote not too long ago.

My program uses PIL or pillow to make a contact sheet. Basically a collage of `self.imageCount` amount of images. I spent allot of time thinking on how to efficiently calculate the size that each image has to be in order to fit all of them on the sheet.

Finally I came up with this

I'll let the function speak for itself.

```py
def calc_size(self):
"""
Calculates size of each image by stating with a maximum height, then slowly 
decreasing it until enough rows and columns can be formed to fit all images.
"""
        self.imageHeight = self.sheetHeight
        self.imageWidth = self.imageHeight * (2/3) # The aspect ratio is located here
        self.rows, self.cols = 1, 1
        while self.rows * self.cols < self.imageCount:   
            self.imageHeight -= 1                             
            self.imageWidth = int(self.imageHeight * (2/3))        
            self.rows = self.calc_rows()                 
            self.cols = self.calc_cols()
"""
The two functions below simply prevent zero division later in the program 
when I calculate the gap between each image
"""

def calc_rows(self):
        if int(self.sheetHeight/self.imageHeight) == 0:
            return 1
        return int(self.sheetHeight/self.imageHeight)

def calc_cols(self):
        if int(self.sheetWidth/self.imageWidth) == 0:
            return 2
        return int(self.sheetWidth/self.imageWidth)
```

So my question is, what is the time complexity of `calc_size`? I've run some tests where I pushed `self.imageCount` up to 10 000 and the runtime never really exceeded 0.004 seconds. This makes me think that it's O(log n). But why...I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, the aspect ratio of the sheet and the aspect ratio of the images are equal, the answer would be O(`sheetHeight`).

Let's consider the worst-case scenario. Let's assume for a moment that `imageCount` is very large, so much so that an image would have to shrink down to one pixel. Then, the number of times the while loop is executed would be equal to `self.sheetHeight - 1`. Therefore, the function would be O(`sheetHeight`).

It seems like in your case the aspect ratios are equal, but assuming they are not equal, then the answer is one of O(`sheetHeight`) or O(`sheetWidth`). Say for example the image width is 1/2 image height. Since 2/3 > 1/2, the limiting direction is the height (the height would hit the limit first). Then the answer would be O(`sheetHeight`).

**Edit:** For a Big O in terms of `imageCount`, consider the following:

For simplicity, I'll assume the aspect ratios of the sheet and image are the same.

Let's take `imageHeight` to be the required height of the image. Say `imageCount = 100`. Then `imageHeight=sheetHeight/10`.

Now, say we multiply `imageCount` by 4. Now the `imageHeight` would have to be `sheetHeight/20`. Thus, we can see that the image height is proportional to `1/sqrt(imageCount)`.

But, the time complexity is actually dependent on `sheetHeight - imageHeight` since that's the number of times the while loop would be executed. Thus, we can say that the solution is O(`sheetHeight - imageHeight`) = O(`sheetHeight - sheetHeight/sqrt(imageCount)`) = O(`1 - 1/sqrt(imageCount)`) (assuming `sheetHeight` is constant).

So, if we take `n = imageCount`, the solution is O(`1-1/sqrt(n)`). This explains why for large imageCounts, the solution approaches a constant time consumption.

Comment: The aspect ratio of the sheet is 5:8. The sheet is landscape and the images on the sheet are portrait. The limiting direction will be the sheet height. So if I understand your answer correctly, the time complexity will be O(n) where n is the height of the sheet, because that is the limiting direction. This explains why the function appears to have constant time because the sheet width and height is set when the object is instantiated and treated as a constant thereafter, combined with the fact that the image height or width are both always positive integers.

Comment: @Christopher Right. But, it's not actually constant time in terms of `imageCount`. Your comment made me realize that the Big O in terms of `imageCount` would actually be a better answer to your question. Let me edit my answer to include that.